# Trademarks - a couple of questions

Tags: trademark

I got a couple of questions about game trademarks.

- When should I submit a trademark for my game if I see that this is a serious project?
- Where do I submit a trademark request? Does it have to be local (In my country)?
- What do I need to be ready to submit a trademark request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your 3 questions is subject to the laws that are applied in your country, also a trademark is a different concept if compared to a registered IP or a registered copyright, and there are also other possible options.

Each country has its own law and usually its own patent office, also do not assume that a registered IP is protected worldwide, this is a political issue and can also affect your distribution strategy.

Comment: Note: 'IP' (or even 'intellectual property') isn't a legal term; instead, it's a blanket term for copyrighted or trademarked content (and the marks and such under which it's protected).  There's no such thing as a 'registered IP' per se.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki yes, but is also one of the few terms that you can use worldwide and be sure that at least other people are getting what you are talking about. You always have to refer to the patent office for the _complete list_ of _IP solutions_

Answer (score 4):

1. I suggest that you contact someone who is able to perform a trademark analysis of the name that you've chosen. It is important to know if the name you have chosen is protected in the corresponding trademark classes about 6-8 months before you launch the game. It is sometimes easy for the board members, investors or the owners to decide for a name that they consider to be "Final" where I have to tell them that the name they've chosen is extremely difficult to protect.
2. It depends on which countries you are interested in protecting your trademark in. The most economical and secure way is to start in one country and then use trademark priority to expand your trademark protection to other countries.
3. You need to know the name you want to protect, if it is protectable and in which classes you will be active in. Generally for games, it is class 9 but depending on the game, it might be more classes.

Comment: Please limit the promotion of your services to your profile page/bio, they're irrelevant in answers.

Comment: (Great answer, though, thanks for posting!)